# IndexError: list index out of range in Tensorflow chatbot

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, chatbot, index-error

```py
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import  WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json', encoding='utf-8').read())

words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbot.model')

def cleanSentance(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bagOfWords(sentence):
    sentence_words = cleanSentance(sentence=sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bagOfWords(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    errThresh = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > errThresh]

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
    print(return_list)
    return return_list

def getResponse(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result

print("Type below")

while True:
    message = input("->")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    print(ints)
    print(intents)
    response = getResponse(ints, intents)
    print(response)
```

When I type something, it comes up with the error:

```
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myusrname\Documents\pythonProject\ArthurAI.py", line 61, in <module>
    response = getResponse(ints, intents)
  File "C:\Users\myusrname\Documents\pythonProject\ArthurAI.py", line 46, in getResponse
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
IndexError: list index out of range***
```

Again, I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg

Also, when training the model (I asked for help with it here: [ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67623823/valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupported-object-type)), the accuracy was all 1, not 0.87453 or 0.98745, just 1, for all the epochs. Is that a good thing?

Inputs include "hello", "how are you" or anything in the intents.json file

Comment: Please include the sample inputs as well as the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong I've added examples

Comment: What is printed out when you run that script?

Comment: The error shown above

Comment: I meant before that traceback.  In your code, you had two ```print``` statements.  What do those print statements print out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the code at the end:

```py
while True:
    message = input("->")
    
    try:
        ints = predict_class(message)
        print(ints)
        print(intents)
        response = getResponse(ints, intents)
        print(response)
        
    except IndexError:
        print("What?")
```

It will try to answer, if can't answer, it will ask again.