# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list). eventhough the data is numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to use BERT model which gives attention, input ids, token type ids.
But when I tried to convert my dataset to TF Dataset, it throws the error below:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I tried looking at [ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67623823/valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupported-object-type) but it didn't solve my issue. Please see the code below.

```
for fold in range(5):
       train_fold = train[train['kfold'] != fold]
       valid_fold = train[train['kfold'] == fold]

       X_train_dataset = (X_train[0][train_fold.index.to_list()], X_train[1] 
          [train_fold.index.to_list()],
          X_train[2][train_fold.index.to_list()])

       train_dataset = (
             tf.data.Dataset
                .from_tensor_slices((X_train_dataset, train_fold['discourse_effectiveness'].values))
              .repeat()
               .shuffle(2048)
              .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
              .prefetch(AUTO)
                )
```

When I look at the type of dataset as below:

```
for x in X_train_dataset:
      print(type(x))
type(train_fold['target'].values)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: It appears to not like lists in NumPy arrays, e.g. .index.to_list()

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same using the way I store the input_ids, attention_mask and token type ids.
I tried using np.zeros((df.shape[0], 256)) and then added the data